# Что сделать чтобы происходил снимок экрана при нажатии Alt+PrtSc на ArchLinux с графической оболочкой I3?

Tags: linux, archlinux, i3wm

Что сделать чтобы происходил снимок экрана при нажатии <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> на ArchLinux с графической оболочкой I3?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: сначала установите программу которая делает скриншоты, затем определите коды нажимаемых клавиш, а уже после в конфиге I3 привяжите нажатие этих клавиш к запуску программы что делает скриншоты. 

Например для sway(аналог i3 для wayland), я использую программу grim что делает скриншоты, для определения кодов клавиш программу wev если конкретнее то команду `wev -f wl_keyboard`, ну и под конец остаётся прописать это в кофиге `~/.config/sway/config` в простом случае будет примерно так: `bindsym Alt_L+Print exec 'grim /path/save/scrinshot'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сначала установите программу которая делает скриншоты, затем определите коды нажимаемых клавиш, а уже после в конфиге I3 привяжите нажатие этих клавиш к запуску программы что делает скриншоты. Например для sway(аналог i3 для wayland), я использую программу grim что делает скриншоты, для определения кодов клавиш программу wev если конкретнее то команду wev -f wl_keyboard, ну и под конец остаётся прописать это в кофиге ~/.config/sway/config в простом случае будет примерно так: bindsym Alt_L+Print exec 'grim /path/save/scrinshot'